# How to model custom relationships involving multiple fields in Hasura?

Tags: postgresql, hasura

I am using Hasura with Postgres database.  I have 2 tables:

**LithicTransaction**

- id: uuid

**LedgerItem**

- id: uuid
- type: text
- referenceId: uuid

**Their relationship:**

- A LithicTransaction may have 0 or 1 LedgerItem.
- A LedgerItem may have 0 or 1 LithicTransaction.

I would like to model these 2 relationships.  I know the underlying SQL statements, but I do not know if it is possible to set these as relationships in Hasura.

**Problem 1:**
Add `LithicTransaction.ledgerItem`, which resolves to 0 or 1 LedgerItem object.

The goal is to be able to write GraphQL query such as:

```
query {
  lithicTransactions {
    id
    ledgerItem {
      id
    } 
  }
}
```

Possible SQL implementation:

```
-- getLedgerItem(lithicTransaction.id)

SELECT * FROM LedgerItem
WHERE type = 'LITHIC_TRANSACTION' AND referenceID = $1
LIMIT 1;

$1 = a specific LithicTransaction.id
```

**Problem 2:**
Add `LedgerItem.lithicTransaction`, which resolves to 0 or 1 LithicTransaction object.

The goal is to be able to write GraphQL query such as:

```
query {
  ledgerItems {
    id
    lithicTransaction {
      id
    } 
  }
}
```

Possible SQL implementation:

```
-- getLithicTransaction(ledgerItem.referenceId, ledgerItem.type)

SELECT * FROM LithicTransaction
WHERE id = $1 AND 'LITHIC_TRANSACTION' = $2
LIMIT 1;

$1 = a specific LedgerItem.referenceId
$2 = a specific LedgerItem.type
```

Please let me know if this is possible with Hasura, or any recommended workarounds.  Thank you.

Comment: Did I understood correctly that entities are related 1-1 ? If so then it's modelled in hasura  as object relationship `LedgerItem.referenceId = LithicTransactionId`. When `LedgerItem.referenceId` is NULL then it's the case of 0.

Comment: No, the relationship is 1-to-0-or-1 in both directions.  To determine whether `LedgerItem.lithicTransaction` resolves to NULL or to an LithicTransaction row, you need to look at BOTH `LedgerItem.type` and `LedgerItem.referenceId`.

Comment: I mean exactly this. In case of referenceId is NULL - it's 1-0. But you need `LedgerItem.type = 'LITHIC_TRANSACTION'`- that's possible but not directly. Look at answer.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly:

- desired relationship is object relationship
- `LedgerItem.type` must be equal 'LITHIC_TRANSACTION'

Hasura now don't support equations as `field` = constant.

But an easy workaround exists:

**1. Create a view with type='LITHIC_TRANSACTION'**

```sql
CREATE VIEW LedgerItemLythic
AS
SELECT * FROM LedgerItem
WHERE
  WHERE type = 'LITHIC_TRANSACTION'
```

**2.Register this view (LedgerItemLythic) in hasura**

**3.Open relationships for this view (LedgerItemLythic) and create manually object relationship**

Define object relationship `LedgerItemLythic.reference_id = LithicTransaction.id`

**4.Open relationships for LithicTransaction and create manually object relationship**
Define object relationship `LithicTransaction.id =  LedgerItemLythic.reference_id`

Mission accomplished.